# Prove Right Angle Side Side (RASS) congruence (from Hartshorne)

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

Prove if two right triangles have one side and the hypotenuse respectively congruent, then the triangles are congruent (from *Hartshorne, Geometry: Euclid and Beyond*).

**Proof**: Let the triangles be $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle A'B'C'$, with angles $\angle B, \angle B'$ right angles, hypotenuses $AC \cong A'C'$, and sides $AB \cong A'B'$.

Extend $AB$ to $D$ such that $AB \cong BD$.  Angle $\angle CBD$ is also a right angle, and so $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DBC$ are congruent by SAS, and $DC \cong AC$.

Similarly extend $A'B'$ to $D'$, which results in $\triangle ADC \cong \triangle A'D'C'$ by SSS.

Observe that $\angle ACD \cong \angle A'C'D'$, with each angle bisected by $BC$ or $B'C'$ respectively. Consequently, $\angle ACB \cong \angle A'C'B'$, and $\triangle ACB \cong A'C'B'$ by AAS.

**Questions**: Is the proof correct and well-written? Is the technique of reflecting the triangle over the unknown leg a good one? Is there a simpler approach? Please verify, critique, or improve the proof and its exposition.

---

### Update

Based on Blue's suggestion, here is a simpler conclusion to the proof:

Similarly extend $A'B'$ to $D'$, which results in $\triangle ADC \cong \triangle A'D'C'$ by SSS.  Thus, $\angle A \cong \angle A'$ and, by SAS, $\triangle ABC \cong \triangle A'B'C'$.

Comment: I believe if you're going to use SSS,SAS AAS in the proof, you may as well just prove it with SAS, since you know that <B is congruent with <B' (Angle), AB is congruent with A'B' (Side #1) and AC is congruent with A'C' (Side #2). Perhaps that works too?

Comment: @MathMan I don't believe that works: Since $\angle B$ is _not_ between $AB$ and $AC$, that would be SSA, which is _not_ always congruent.  To use SAS this way, we'd need to know $\angle A \cong \angle A'$.

Comment: @SRobertJames: Your proof looks okay to me, provided the notion that *halves of congruent angles are congruent* is in play. (At the foundations level, it can be tricky to know what's allowed, since different authors can present results in different orders.) Note that your earlier comment to MathMan suggests a way forward that's "safer" in this regard: once you have $\triangle ADC\cong\triangle A'D'C'$, you can say $\angle A\cong\angle A'$ so that $\triangle ABC\cong\triangle A'B'C'$ by SAS. No subtle angle-algebra required.

Comment: @Blue Your suggestion also makes the proof simpler and shorter - all win, no downside.  Revised accordingly.  (PS If you make your comment an answer, I will accept it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof looks okay to me, provided the notion that *halves of congruent angles are congruent* is in play. (At the foundations level, it can be tricky to know what's allowed, since different authors can present results in different orders.)

Note that your comment to MathMan suggests a way forward that's "safer" in this regard: Once you have $\triangle ADC\cong\triangle A'D'C'$, you can say $\angle A\cong\angle A'$ so that $\triangle ABC\cong\triangle A'B'C'$ by SAS. No subtle angle-algebra required.