# Why does Euclid need the Parallel Postulate to prove equal chords are equidistant from the center?

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry, math-history

[Euclid's Proposition III.14](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII14.html) proves that chords are of equal length iff they are equidistant from the center.  Euclid's proof is long and complicated, repeatedly invoking the Pythagorean Theorem, which ultimately depends on the Parallel Postulate.

This is very surprising, given that a very simple proof *not* dependent on the Parallel Postulate is available (and Euclid always avoids the Parallel Postulate where possible, e.g. the first 30 propositions of Book I):

> Let $AB$ and $A'B'$ be equal length chords in $\bigcirc O$.  Then $OA \cong OA', OB \cong OB', AB \cong A'B'$, so $\triangle ABO \cong \triangle A'B'O$ by SSS, and their altitudes are equal.  QED.

One might object that we haven't explicitly proven that congruent triangles have equal altitudes. But this too is easily proven, esp. since Euclid has already proven that this altitude bisects the chord ([III.3](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII3.html)):

> From $O$, drop the altitude to $AB$ at $M$ and to $A'B'$ at $M'$.  Since $AB \cong A'B'$, $MA$ (which is half of $AB$) is congruent to $MA'$ (half of $A'B'$), so $\triangle MAO \cong \triangle M'A'O$ by ASA, and $MO \cong M'O$.

Finally, the converse comes almost as easy:

> Given $OM \cong OM'$, then $\triangle OMA \cong OM'A'$ and $\triangle OMB \cong OM'B'$ by HL (aka [RASS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4626007/prove-right-angle-side-side-rass-congruence-from-hartshorne)), so $AB \cong A'B'$.

Although Euclid has not yet proven RASS, [the proof is easy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4626007/prove-right-angle-side-side-rass-congruence-from-hartshorne) and does *not* require the Parallel Postulate.

**Questions:**

1. Are the proofs above correct? Aside from why Euclid didn't use them, can you verify or critique these proofs?
2. Why didn't Euclid use them, given that they are simpler, shorter, more explicit, and don't require the Parallel Postulate?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thanks you for catching that: it should have been SSS as you state (fixed).  But SSS most certainly does _not_ depend on the Parallel Postulate; SSS holds in hyperbolic geometry as well.  See [Euclid's proof in I.8](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI8.html).

Comment: I would assume this is just because Euclid basically doesn't talk about circles at all until Book III.

Comment: @EricWofsey But the proposition is III.14! Entirely about circles.

Comment: Right, that's my point.  Euclid avoids the parallel postulate for as long as he can in Book I, but by Book III he's already been using it for a long time and doesn't bother avoiding it anymore.

Comment: @EricWofsey Even if we accept the idea that once he's begun using the Parallel Postulate he uses it freely, why the need for such a complicated proof, when the one above is so simple and obvious?

Comment: His proof really doesn't seem much more complicated than yours. A little more complicated, but not a lot.